# Building vmware tools for i386 architecture

Tags: centos, compiling, vmware, rpmbuild

Trying to build vmware tools for my `32` bit `Centos 7`. I took source from [github](https://github.com/vmware/open-vm-tools)

Trying to follow instruction with small changes:

```
autoreconf -i 
./configure --without-kernel-modules ./configure --enable-deploypkg=no --without-ssl --without-icu --without-dnet --without-gtkm3
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

What I should do now? Where is output and how to install it? Should I expect RPM?

Answer (score 1):

1. `autoreconf -i` - produces from the `configure.ac` the `configure` script which you call on the next step.
2. `./configure ...` - produces from templates (`Makefile.in`, `some_file.in`) output files (`Makefile`, `somefile`) considering parameters that you pass too `configure` script. On this steps detect your CPU, compilers and so on.
3. `make` - compile all files (maybe something else).
4. `make install` - install all files to system directories.
5. `ldconfig` - update system library cache and system library links.

If you did this steps without errors, then you have successfully installed **vmware tools**.